# EXCEL - Multiple Arrays within COUNTIF formula

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, sum, countif

Attempting to count:

Named range "STATUS" if the value of the cells equals Reserved, Blocked, Pending OR Archive

AND

Named range "COMPANY" equals Company A, Company B OR Company C.

I'm also counting multiple other criteria, all of the which are working. When I added the array for the Company the formula is no longer counting the Status.

Here is the formula I'm using:

```
=SUM((COUNTIFS(DATES,">="&A19,DATES,"<"&EDATE(A19,1),AGENT,"JOHN DOE",COMPANY,{"COMPANY A","COMPANY B","COMPANY C"},STATUS,{"Reserved","Blocked","Pending","Archive"})))
```

Any help is greatly appreciated and thank you in advance!

Comment: are you summing a single number? `=SUM((3))`

Comment: Yes, i'm expecting the output to be a single number

Comment: `COUNTIFS` already returns a single number, no need to sum it with nothing else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
=SUM((COUNTIFS(DATES,">="&A19,DATES,"<"&EDATE(A19,1),AGENT,"JOHN DOE",COMPANY,{"COMPANY A";"COMPANY B";"COMPANY C"},STATUS,{"Reserved","Blocked","Pending","Archive"})))
```

or

```
=SUM((COUNTIFS(DATES,">="&A19,DATES,"<"&EDATE(A19,1),AGENT,"JOHN DOE",COMPANY,{"COMPANY A","COMPANY B","COMPANY C"},STATUS,{"Reserved";"Blocked";"Pending";"Archive"})))
```

Note the `;` instead of `,` in arrays. For details on why to use semi-colon instead of comma see [this](https://excelxor.com/2014/09/28/countifs-multiple-or-criteria-for-one-or-two-criteria_ranges/).

If you want to use your formula it should be as follows

```
=SUM((COUNTIFS(DATES,">="&A19,DATES,"<"&EDATE(A19,1),AGENT,"JOHN DOE",COMPANY,"COMPANY A",STATUS,{"Reserved","Blocked","Pending","Archive"}))) +
SUM((COUNTIFS(DATES,">="&A19,DATES,"<"&EDATE(A19,1),AGENT,"JOHN DOE",COMPANY,"COMPANY B",STATUS,{"Reserved","Blocked","Pending","Archive"}))) + 
SUM((COUNTIFS(DATES,">="&A19,DATES,"<"&EDATE(A19,1),AGENT,"JOHN DOE",COMPANY,"COMPANY C",STATUS,{"Reserved","Blocked","Pending","Archive"})))
```

Comment: Using ; instead of , in the arrays worked! Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

you can create additional column with all of the conditions you need as if inside an `IF` condition, e.g.

```
=(A2>=A19) * ((B2="COMPANY A") + (B2="COMPANY B")))
```

and then `=COUNTIF(ALL_CONDITIONS, ">0")`

Comment: Thank you, this is a good workaround, but I was hoping to avoid any extraneous columns.